# template to check for existence of overloaded member function

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I try to specialize a template if a class has a special member function like this (found here in another example):

```
template <typename T>
class has_begin
{
    typedef char one;
    typedef long two;

    template <typename C> static one test( decltype( &C::AnyFunc) ) ;
    template <typename C> static two test(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
    enum { Yes = sizeof(has_begin<T>::test<T>(0)) == 1 };
    enum { No = !Yes };
};
```

This works well until `AnyFunc` is overloaded:

```
class B : public vector<int>
{
public:
    void AnyFunc() const;
    void AnyFunc();
};
```

How can I rewrite my test code to get a "Yes" from my template?

Comment: Good question. A very trivial problem which can go silently undetected due to SFINAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the version which works:

```
    template <typename C> static one test( decltype(((C*)0)->AnyFunc())* ) ;
```

If you want to verify that object has const function, use this:

```
    template <typename C> static one test( decltype(((const C*)0)->AnyFunc())* ) ;
```

this version will not detect function with arguments:

```
class B : public std::vector<int>
{
public:
    //void AnyFunc() const;
    //void AnyFunc();
    int AnyFunc(int);
};
```

Comment: @Klaus That was why I added `*` after `decltype()`... I checked that it worked before posting: http://ideone.com/8Tli7t

Comment: After reading the second answer, I got your solution to run in my environment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, I forget the * after the decltype! Sorry for my fault! I got this to work after looking behind the std::add_pointer from the second answer.

Comment: `std::add_pointer` is better than simple `*` since you can't have pointer to reference. On the other hand it is a new C++11 feature, not always implemented (especially in older versions of compilers)

Answer (score 2):

The use of an overloaded function name without arguments (13.4p1) must be resolved to a single overload (13.4p4), otherwise substitution failure will occur.

If you are testing for the existence of a member function then you should know the arguments you plan to call it with:

```
    template <typename C> static one test(
        typename std::add_pointer<decltype(std::declval<C>().AnyFunc())>::type);
```

In general, you can use a variadic template and a pattern similar to `result_of`:

```
    template <typename C, typename... Args> static one test(
        typename std::add_pointer<decltype(
            std::declval<C>(std::declval<Args>()...).AnyFunc())>::type);
```

Using `add_pointer` allows this to work with function return types that are not allowable as function argument types (e.g. `void`).